# Cucumber-extentreports embedded screenshots are not displayed

Tags: cucumber-java

I have added maven dependency for extent reports :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>.
```

In the runner class I have specified the plugin in Cucucmber options:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features={"src/test/java/features/Exception.feature"},strict = true
        ,glue={"com.selenium.wrapper","stepDefinitaion"},
        format = { "pretty","html:target/site/cucumber-pretty","html:target/cucumber-report","json:target/cucumber.json" },
        plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:output/report.html"}
```

And In the @After hook i have added the code to add the screenshot:

//* add code to take screenshot and save it

```
 Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath("path of the screenshot");
```

After execution a blank image is added:
[image 2 shows the blank screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYWy4.png)

Comment: Are you able to manually look at the screenshot file?

Comment: yes the screenshots are available at specified path

Answer (score 0):

Did you try saving the screenshot as *.png* file.I had faced the same issue while embedding screenshots which were saved as *.jpg* files.

Answer (score 0):

For Cucumber extended report embed is not working due to this, we have to save the image and then

```
File sourcePath = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); 
File destinationPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/test-report/extent-report/screenshots/" + screenshotName + ".png"); 
copyFile(sourcePath, destinationPath); Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath("./screenshots/"+screenshotName+".png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the screenshot with the ".png" extension. Some issue while embedding the image with .jpg files. I have faced the same issue and I have modified the .jpg to .png and the screenshots are embedded to the extent report.